# Accord du verbe avec un nom collectif

Tags: grammaire, accord

Dans cette phrase :

> Julie et sa bande d'amis sont descendu(e)s du train.

J'aurais fortement tendance à accorder "descendus" au masculin pluriel, tout en considérant que l'accorder au féminin pluriel ne peut pas être grammaticalement faux.

Qu'en pensez-vous, et pour aller plus loin, croyez-vous que cela change si on écrit :

> Julie et sa bande sont descendu(e)s du train.

De plus, que pensez-vous de :

> La bande d'amis est descendue du train.

Par rapport à :

> La bande d'amis sont descendus du train.

Comment: Ici il n'y a pas vraiment de problème, vu que *bande* est féminin, non ? La question se poserait si c'était "*Julie et son groupe sont/est descendu(e)s*" par exemple. Je ne comprends pas vraiment le problème sinon.

Comment: Justement, bande est au féminin mais on peut a priori accorder au masculin, enfin c'est ma question en tout cas. Pour le cas dont tu parles, je ne vois, a priori, pas autre chose que le masculin pluriel.

Comment: Pour moi il n'y a aucune raison d'accorder au masculin, si on a deux noms féminins on accorde au féminin. Ah pour "amis", qui seraient composé de garçons et de filles, c'est ça ?

Comment: Étant donné qu'on peut accorder les noms collectifs au pluriel (j'ai déjà lu "un troupeau de vaches se bousculaient", et non "qui se bousculaient" qui serait déjà moins surprenant), pourquoi ne pas considérer le genre aussi ?

Comment: Dans ce cas-là, c'est une [syllepse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse) classique. Comme "*La plupart des gens a/ont un problème avec ...*" c'est grammaticalement correct d'utiliser le singulier mais sémantiquement plus clair d'utiliser le pluriel. Les deux sont autorisés, on préfère généralement privilégier le sens à la grammaire.

Answer (score 2):

Tout d'abord, il faut rappeler la règle d'accord de l'auxilliaire *être* : il accorde son participe passé **toujours** en fonction du sujet. Dans ton exemple, il suffit de se poser la question suivante :

```
Qui est descendu du train? Julie et ses amis!
```

pour savoir comment accorder ton participe passé.

Ensuite, commençons par le plus simple:

> La bande d'amis sont descendus du train.

Cette phrase n'est pas fausse, mais elle sera peu utilisée suite à ces raisons :

- `La bande d'amis` est décrit comme étant au singulier puisqu'il s'agit d'un seul groupe, donc le verbe "sonne" mieux au singulier
- `La` étant un pronom féminin, on peut accorder le verbe au féminin.

On préférera par conséquent utiliser l'accord de ta 3ème phrase, même s'il s'agit de plusieurs personnes, on parle d'un seul groupe :

> La bande d'amis est descendue du train.

Ensuite, concernant les 2 premières phrases, il existe plusieurs possibilités, étant donné qu'il s'agit d'une énumération (donc forcément pluriel):

- plusieurs sujets masculins -> accord au masculin
- plusieurs sujets féminins -> accord au féminin
- un *ou plusieurs* sujets féminin avec *au moins* un sujet masculin -> accord au masculin

NB: Cette dernière possibilité peut être amenée à pouvoir être accordée au féminin, la langue française risquant d'évoluer dans ce sens (ce n'est pas encore le cas à l'heure actuelle), donc ta phrase ressemblera à :

> Julie et sa bande d'amis sont descendus du train.

*À noter que l'on sait que la bande d'amis est composée d'au moins d'un garçon/homme, sinon* ***amis*** *s'écrirait avec un* ***e*** *comme ça :* ***amies***

Comment: J'aimerais que ce soit aussi simple mais "Un groupe de coureurs sont passés au contrôle" est a priori considéré comme correct.

Comment: Il est vrai que l'accord au pluriel d'`un groupe de coureur` est correct, mais il est rare de voir quelqu'un l'utiliser; les 2 orthographes sont acceptées, alors autant ne pas se prendre la tête et n'utiliser que la version "logique" sachant que la 2nde sonnera fausse, même pour français natif

Comment: Mais si l'accord au pluriel d'`un groupe de coureurs` est correct, pourquoi celui d'`un groupe d'amis` est (je te cite) "totalement faux" ?

Comment: D'`une bande d'amis` voulais-je écrire.

Answer (score -2):

> 1.`Julie et sa bande d'amis sont descendu(e)s du train.`

L'accord se fait normalement avec le noyau du syntagme nominal et on n'essaie pas de considérer l'action en tant que « distribuée » sur une réalité seconde (les éléments, les personnes de la bande) impliquée par ce qui est signifié (l'ensemble,  bande ), c'est à dire que l'on doit écrire « descendues ».

- Julie et sa bande d'amis sont descendues du train.

Mon opinion à ce sujet est qu'il n'est pas dans l'intérêt de la langue de diversifier les pratiques grammaticales plus que nécessaire. On a l'avantage dans le présent système d'une simplicité de raisonnement due à l'uniformité (« La bande est descendu**e** du train. »).

Je ne pense pas que l'économie de l'anglais dans « The government **are** now at lunch. » vaille la peine en français d'une règle spéciale quand on peut dire « Les membres du gouvernement sont à leur déjeuner. ». Si on  s'alignait sur le modèle de l'anglais on devrait pouvoir dire « La bande sont descendu(e)s du train. » mais, à mon avis, cela va trop à l'encontre du principe que la consistance est essentielle ; un mot ne peut pas avoir deux statuts grammaticaux dans une même explication : ici, « bande » est forcément singulier et pluriel.

Il existe actuellement une tendance en France, dont on peut avoir vent sur le FSE (je ne sais pas dans quelle question), qui s'intéresse à l'accord avec le complément du nom.
Comme « amis » est le masculin pluriel, sans plus de contexte que n'en fourni la phrase, on est enclin à supposer que les amis de Julie ne sont pas nécessairement que des personnes du sexe féminin et « amis » représente un groupe mixte. Selon le principe que le masculin l'emporte, ou ici le masculin déguisé en « mixte » il semblerait indiqué d'écrire « descendus ».

- Julie et sa bande d'amis sont descendus du train.

Si les amies de Julie n'étaient que des filles/femmes et alors on utiliserait la forme « amies » et il n'y aurait pas de difficulté.

- Julie et sa bande d'amies sont descendues du train.

> 2.`Julie et sa bande sont descendu(e)s du train.`

Comme je le souligne au « 1. », « Julie et sa bande sont descendues du train. » est la seule possibilité selon la grammaire standard.

> 3.`La bande d'amis est descendue du train.` par opposition à `La bande d'amis sont descendus du train.`

Ma conclusion à de sujet se trouve au « 1. » mais c'est une première approximation, je n'ai jamais fait une étude profonde de cette question. Il n'y a pas de doute que comment l'action est applicable en relation avec le sujet  puisse être déterminant et une influence justificatrice, mais seulement dans certain cas. Dans d'autres, il n'y a pas de guide. Cela augmente la complexité, il me semble.

- La troupe des soldats serpentai(en)t entre les petites collines.

On est plus enclin à attribuer l'action à la troupe qu'aux soldats ; ainsi on sera peut-être assez souvent confronté à des dilemmes résultant de l'adhérence à une règle diversifiée alors que la règle traditionnelle ne présente que le problème du choix de verbe en correspondance avec un sujet. C'est, je crois, parce que l'on veut en « faire faire de trop » aux mots que l'on se trouve devant ce problème d'accord.

Dans le cas suivant on ne trouve plus une « polarisation » de l'action mais un couple d'interprétations toutes deux également acceptables.

- La bande d'amis s'organisai(en)t pour  reprendre le contrôle du village.

Dans ce cas-ci on a l'impression de pouvoir parler de deux idées, l'une référant à une organisation générale de la bande elle-même et l'autre à des organisations individuelles, mais ni l'un ni l'autre des deux accords ne nous assure d'une signification précise.

Pour la première idée on peut dire plus précisément ceci.

- La bande d'amis se dotait d'une organisation de groupe pour reprendre le contrôle du village.

Pour la seconde la possibilité suivante convient.

- Chacun des amis dans la bande s'organisait pour une reprise (en groupe) du contrôle du village.

Ceci montre qu'un apparent problème d'accord disparait si l'on s'en tient à des relations plus spécifiques.